# Calculate the sum of all multiples of 7 and 11 below 926 using C++

Tags: c++

I need to find the sum of all multiples of 7 and 11 below 926. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

int sum = 0;

    for (for i = 1; sum<926; i++)

        
            sum = sum + 7*i + 11*i;
    
    
    std::cout << "The sum is "<<sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for some reason this is returning 990

Comment: It seems that you don't understand the question. A "Multiple of x" doesn't mean you need to multiply each index value with x. It means the index value can be divided by x without leaving a remainder.

Comment: Which result did you expect?

Comment: Hint: this should be a simple mathematical formula, without any looping or manual counting. Like all other silly puzzles from useless coding/hacking/competition web sites, all it is, is a programming puzzle and offers nothing of value to anyone who actually wants to learn C++. It's only a list of programming puzzles.

Comment: @Yunnosch it is 7 + 11. Lowest multiple of 18.

Comment: @Cem True, luckily I did not make the same mistake when I converted the comment into an answer. Funnily the 77 pops up again in the discussion of "and".

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry, I didn't see the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating
(7+11)* (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10) == 18*55 == 990

Your program stops at 990 because it is the first number > 926.

This is calculating "the lowest cumulative multiple of (7+11) greater or equal 926".
This is of course not what you want.

In order to find "the sum of all multiples of 7 and 11 below 926" you should check all numbers below 926 for being a multiple of 7 or 11.

I am not sure whether you are supposed to only add up those which are a multiple of 7 AND a multiple of 11 (which would be only the multiples of 77) or whether you are supposed to add up all which are a multiple of 7 and those which are a multiple of 11. This is a unclear area between English phrasing and programming expressions.
Read the assignment again, it might be clearer in there.

So lets simplify to "the sum of all multiples of 7 and 11 below 78", for discussing the algorithm instead of language precision.

The answer is either:
7+11+14+21+22+28+33+35+42+44+49+55+56+63+66+70+77
or
77

After you decided you will easily find a way to detect a multiple of something. (Hint: read up on `%` operator).

I intentionally do not give a full solution, or even code for it, because of:
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

There is a fable about Guass quickly responding to a teacher busy-work assignment to sum the numbers 1..100.   Guass quickly answered 5050; that is (100 + 1) * 100/2.   For an evenly spaced sequence, this can be summarized as (a[0] + a[n-1]) * n /2; since the average value of the sequence will be (a[0] + a[n-1]) / 2; and the number of elements n.

Thus, the sequence 2,4,...200 = (202 / 2) * 100 or 1010.

And the sequence 77,154,231, ... 77 * n will be ((77 * (n+1))/2) * n.

So, you just have to figure out N.